# Create a non root user for Linux MySQL with minimal right as using root is not secure

Tags: mysql

General rule for root MySQL user is from security point of view:

"Do not use root for any web application for MySQL connection, Select, Update, or Delete queries. Instead of create and use another MySQL user with minimal right."

Ok. What are minimal rights needed for such user, and how can create it and assign minimal rights in MySQL ? I haven't found any guideline / article about this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has probably been answered a few times already but here we go again.

Here is how cPanel does this and you might want to follow:

1. create database db1
2. create a localhost user with some password
3. assign the user to the database
4. assign the needed privileges to this user for that database (cPanel assigns them globally for all tables in the database but you can assign them per table or even per table column)

The most used privileges for table/index manipulation are ALTER CREATE DROP and INDEX

The most used ones for data manipulation are DELETE INSERT SELECT UPDATE

Here is a more complete list for MySQL 5.7:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html

You assign privileges using the GRANT command as explained here for MySQL 5.7.: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

In most cases you will grant access to a user on localhost but you can add some network address or even some wildcard address that includes %

Let's grant user db1_user only the SELECT privilege (only read data) on all tables of database db1 using the password mypass:

grant select on db1.* to db1_user@localhost identified by 'mypass';

You can use the mysql utility to issue SQL statements as root or some other user that has GRANT privileges on that database object. Running mysql as root:

$ mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 1):

You grant rights according to what your application needs. If all your application requires is `SELECT` on a single table, then that's all the user should be granted.

There's no "guide" on this, as it's completely depending on the application owner understanding what the requirements of the application actually are.